# How to update related layer style in featuregroup in leaflet API

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to set style for related layers in a featureGroup using Leaflet API, here is my code:

```
var highlightStyle = {
    color: '#9b1d41', 
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.6,
    fillOpacity: 0.65,
    fillColor: '#9b1d41'
};

$wnd.mapareas.eachLayer(function(layerOnMap) {
    layerOnMap.setStyle(highlightStyle);
    console.log(layerOnMap);
});
```

I could see in the log that layer has new set style , but its not visible on map, like color is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

For GeoJSON layers (which are FeatureGroups) you could do like this

```
new L.GeoJSON(mp, {
    style: highlightStyle 
});
```

For standard FeatureGroup

```
new L.FeatureGroup([mp1, mp2]).setStyle(highlightStyle);
```